# Class-D amplifier of present vs Class-A of the past

Tags: amplifier

Quite a sensitive question, and perhaps on the edge of the [off-topic](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/should-home-theater-non-studio-or-production-related-equipment-questions-be-on).

But I'm interested in a balanced view on the technology evolution over recent decades. The semiconductor industry made a huge leap, clock frequency has increased enormously, and intuitively one would expect that the PWM amplification (i.e. Class-D) should have improved over the time. Does it still lagging in terms of characteristics behind the direct amplification of Class-A? Could compare it with the transistor Class-A technology of 80-s? or 90-s?

Comment: I do not mind. Is it possible to move it or should I start a new question there?

Answer (score 1):

Other than unmeasurable parameters only detectable by audiophools, a good class D amplifier can produce the same ultimate sound to a human observer given the same source signal and same speakers as any other good audio amplifier.

The main difference is that class D amplifiers are much more efficient.  With modern electronic components, they can now be cheaper because the additional electronic parts don't cost as much as the mechanical parts to deal with and get rid of the heat in other types of amplifiers.  For battery operated equipment, the efficiency itself is also a important advantage.